# Pokemon texture model

Tags: texturing

i'm new to blender and i have found some pokemons model i like but there is a problem with the eyes. Here's a picture of the issue and a link to the site where i've found the models(it's the models that have .fbx and .dae file only):[image]

https://free3d.com/3d-models/pokemon

I use the FBX format model.

Comment: Could you make your question a bit more specific? What do you mean by "there is a problem with the eyes"?

Comment: Ah, I see -- you downloaded this model: https://free3d.com/3d-model/dragonite-pokemon-69889.html

And, on opening it in Blender (can confirm this in v2.81), the eyes are outlined in black skin rather than orange (in Eevee) (in Cycles, the eyes seem to become white 'blobs', and the patch of skin around them has an undesirable shadow artifact).

I think it would help if you added image to/link of the Dragonite model you downloaded to help clarify your question for others.

Comment: Well, i've downloaded a LOT of models that seems to be from the same person. Some model are correct but others have the issue shown in the picture.

Comment: I see. I don't have a fix yet, but, for others investigating: I think this is related to the Alpha Channel in the texture applied to the eyes. It seems as if black in the image is being interpreted as alpha; switching the Material to Alpha Clip and playing with the threshold gets me close to the look I think LynxArtise expects, except it also removes the black throughout the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem stems from the .fbx importer not by default treating the eye's image texture as having a transparency channel (an Alpha channel, in addition to the RGB color channels), although I am not sure why this would happen on some but not other models downloaded from the same site and created by the same modeler. Still, this seems to be the cause in the particular case of the Dragonite model you downloaded.

By default, this situation results in an import that renders like (note that this is in Eevee; the problem exhibits distinct visual problems in Cycles, but presumably the fix would be similar there, accounting for the somewhat different handling of Transparency in Cycles):

[image]

If we open a Shader Editor window, and select the eye material (an image texture that is mostly transparent, except for a small section in which the eye is painted; note that this is likely to be the last of four Materials on the Dragonite model, for you), we see something like:

[image]

There are two issues here:

1. The material's "blend mode" is set to Opaque, which does not use the Alpha Channel, and so ignores transparency.
2. The Color rather than Alpha output from the Image Texture has been connected on fbx-import to the Principled BSDF Shader Node's Alpha input channel, so Black-White is being interpreted as Alpha. If we fix these problems (see squared areas in this image), the problem appears to be fixed:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It work.